# Angularjs: How to multiply total got from total filter in angularjs for showing total in different currency value?

Tags: angularjs

[image]I am using angularjs for a reporting app and i need to show total value in multiple currency. I obtained total making my own filter and applying it as such:
My filter file

```
app.filter('sumByColumn', function () {
    return function (collection, column) {
      var total = 0;
      var ic = 0;
      collection.forEach(function (item) {
        total += parseInt(item[column]);
      }); 
     return total;
   }; })
```

I implemented total in my table and shows value as such:

```
 <strong>NC Rs. {{ vm.sameNameInNgrepeatFromTableList | sumByColumn: 'slValue' }}</strong>
```

Now i want to show total in Indian currency multiplying total by 1.6.How can i Implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made another filter using same filter above:

```
app.filter('ic', function () {
    return function (collection, column) {
      var total = 0;
      var ic=0;
      collection.forEach(function (item) {
        total += parseInt(item[column]);
        ic= total *1.6;
      });  
      return ic;
    };
  })
```

And used that filter for currency conversion as follows

```
<strong>IC INR. {{ vm.sameNameInNgrepeatFromTableList | ic : 'slValue' }}</strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably could use something like

`<strong>NC Rs. {{ vm.sameNameInNgrepeatFromTableList * 1.6 | sumByColumn: 'slValue' }}</strong>`
Please take reference from below code snippet:

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.quantity = 1;
    $scope.price = 10;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
   Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="quantity">
      Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price">

      <p> Toal Default = {{ (quantity * price) | currency }}</p>
      <p>Total in INR = {{ (quantity * price) | currency :"INR " }}</p>

  </div>
</div>
```